# out of memory : Java heap space gradle build error in Android Studio

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

When I build my **Ionic v1** project in `Android Studio (version-3.1.3)` it gives me the following error:

```
Out of memory: Java heap space.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
<em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
```

I have added following contents in directory **home/user/.gradle/gradle.properties** file

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=1024m -Xmx1024m
```

I have already try different solutions and change the memory size in **gradle.properties** file but still isn't working.

Can you help me how can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m`` with this I can compile and run a 250k lines-of-code app.

Comment: I have added org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m in gradle.properties and build the project but still getting the same error.

Comment: Does your project set different values in the local gradle.properties, thus overriding the global values from /home/user?

Comment: No, my project does not have any local gradle.properties. In my system only  single home/user/.gradle/gradle.properties file and how can I know gradle.properties files changes are reflected or not in the project because I have trying to different way but not resolved this error.

Comment: Hmm... so you manually deleted your local gradle.properties file, yes? Because by default, when you create an Android Studio project, _every_ required configuration is created locally in the project. Allow me to ask, why you delete your local configuration? I always find it perfectly useful to be able to configure every project on its own, be it multidexing, predex libraries, jvm args, keystores, etc. So on every workstation I get a valid configuration. Honestly, try to configure your jvm local in the project.

Comment: I have not create project in Android studio. I created the project in terminal and add the Android platform becuase I am using ionic V1 and after create the project I imported the Android folder (which is inside my ionic project ) in Android studio so there is no local gradle.properties file so I created the global gradle.properties file in system.

Comment: Ok sorry, then I can't tell what your config might look like. There are many folders and files involved and it looks to me that some are found or not found where the are expected and therefore your gradle doesn't really know what's going on. It looks as if your global file has no effect, so there will be something on some other place. But without more information, your folder structure and all files contained there I can not help any further.

Comment: Please add your logs, so we may get more idea on it.

Comment: Found below 3 errors from log: 1) org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation '/home/user/Desktop/android-studio/gradle/gradle-4.4'. 2) Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Cannot evaluate module CordovaLib : org.gradle.api.artifacts.ProjectDependency.getProjectConfiguration()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration; 3) Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: By first log error I can see, there is issue with sync gradle, it may get corrupted. 
Try to 
rm -rf ~/project/.gradle
also deleted .gradle folder contend. then try to rebuild your project. 
It may solve your issue.